# How can I get the URL parameter after the domain name in php/apache configuration?

Tags: php, url, web, webserver

Eg, for a website I have, website.com/abcd, I need to extract the 'abcd' variable and store in a database. If a user visits website.com/abcd it redirects to a 404 page. I have been tinkering with .htaccess but not getting anywhere.

Comment: print_r($_SERVER); those are the variables you have to play with

Comment: _I have been tinkering with .htaccess_ Maybe it would be useful to see what you have done in there

Comment: Add as custom 404-handler that persists to DB.
`ErrorDocument 404 /persist_to_db_and_probably_show_error.php`. What has this to do with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pop the below into a .htaccess file...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

... then use `<?php print_r($_SERVER);?>` to show variables that your server will let you use.

The above htaccess code is pretty basic; if the file/directory that's being requested doesn't physically exist, requests will be redirected to `./index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom error-handler instead of the builtin to your `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /handle_404.php
```

In the handle_404.php you can do access all information you need:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
echo "The url you requested (${_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}), does not exist.";
// do whatever else you want (e.g. persist to DB)
```